# Read Ansible command invocation

Tags: ansible

Is it possible to detect within a playbook what the Ansible invocation was? Specifically I'd like to detect whether the "--ask-vault-pass" option was supplied, and if not, exit the playbook.

Comment: Why? If you include a vaulted file somewhere in your inventory/play/role then Ansible will fail if the Vault password hasn't been supplied.

Comment: From what I've seen that's not true, the copy module just copied the encrypted file. Besides, I want to detect immediately that a Vault password was not provided and yell accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way might be to use another task to check the content of your file. For example,

```
- name: check if a string is in the content
  failed_when: "expected_string" not in "{{ file.content }}"
```

If the vault-pass/file is not supplied, the file can not be decrypted. However, you will also need to make sure the ansible.cfg file is not configured with the file path already.